# How to share .scn file as .usdz file?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, usdz, scnscene

I am creating an app where users can scan objects in 3D, I have a scene which I can easily save in documents directory and share it in .scn format, but I want to share this .scn file as .usdz file via UIActivityController.

Basically I am using this library https://github.com/StandardCyborg/StandardCyborgCocoa

In this library, a scene file is saved as .gltf format, but I want to share this .gltf file which is not supported on iOS devices. Apple only support .usdz file format. So, I want to convert this .gltf file into .usdz file before sharing.

I have been searching different solutions over internet for a week, but nothing is working till now.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented, but `SCNScene`'s [`write`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write) method works with a .usdz URL, at least since iOS 14.7. This is what I'm using in my app.

Comment: Do you mean it converts scn to USDZ?

Comment: It should convert any `SCNScene` in memory, which could be loaded from a `.scn` file.

Comment: Can you show me a code on how to do it?